# Disable the "Close" button for questions with a bounty in the Low Quality Review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, bounties, low-quality-posts

I just received [this Low Quality Review queue item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4125339#./4125295?&_suid=139299808683700953921823161234), which has a bounty attached to it:

[image]

Since you can't close questions with bounties on them (you receive the message "This question has an open bounty on it and cannot be closed"), the "Close" button is not an option here.

Granted, this is probably some bizarre edge case of a low-quality question surviving long enough to allow a bounty to be put on it, but can the "Close" button be disabled in this case, since it's not a valid option?

Alternately, should questions with bounties even show up in this queue since the only choices are "Look Good", "Edit" or "Skip"?

Comment: I think a better solution is not pushing a VLQ flag to the queue if the question has a bounty, or perhaps just flat-out disabling the VLQ flag on a bountied question and forcing them to custom flag it, since only a moderator could handle this situation.

Comment: Hmm.. One could argue this example deserves to be closed anyways. Is this a case where a moderator flag would be useful?

Comment: @animuson - that was my initial thought process, too, and I almost wordered the question that way, but I could see someone editing the question into an acceptable shape.  I could go either way, I just found the scenario very strange.

Comment: I just had the same issue. It would be really good if questions with bounty would not get into the low quality queue, because you can't really do anything with them anyway.